# "wants to make changes" dialogue

Tags: security

Suppose I want to run an application I have downloaded and I am prompted with the following dialogue.

[image]

If I enter my username and password, being user that has administrator privileges, and press ok, does this mean the process can do absolutely anything (e.g. change my password or install a keylogger)?

[This Q&A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/117885/37955) is the closest thing I could find on this site, but I wanted a more conclusive answer.

Comment: The answer is yes you give the process root access which on OS X gives complete access - I can't think how to make this longer to become an answer

Comment: @Mark ok thank you. Just let me know if you think the question is not suitable for the site or something. I am also interested whether it is possible to see exactly what changes would be made, like in the Q&A I linked to. In the linked Q&A, the installer is mentioned, which I think does not play a role here. Perhaps I can extend the question like this.